# Load a .csv file using Neo4j in NetBeans

Tags: csv, netbeans, neo4j

I am a beginner. I want to use Neo4j in NetBeans and I added “graph-algorithms-algo-3.3.0.0.jar” in my project library. Should I add other files? I want to load a .csv dataset and I want to use the Louvain algorithm for feature clustering , and then,  I will classify it using a classification method in Weka.
When i load a .csv dataset with this code, an error appears.
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/e:/Data.csv' AS line
Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you embed Neo4j into your java project ? Or are you using Neo4j remotely ? 
Can you give us the error that appears ?